# Data Model for home automation sensor network. Infer type of instance variable from generic type?

Tags: java, data-modeling

For a home automation project I'm struggling to come up with a data model to represent the various sensors and measurements. I will describe the situation and my reasoning and then hopefully someone can give me a pointer on how to proceed. I'm working in Java.

I want to model various types of sensors. A sensors can measure either temperature, humidity, air pressure, etc. Each sensor has unique identifier, a location and a description. I also want to store previous measurements in a database for generating statistics and historical views.

From an object oriented perspective I'd create a Sensor class that's extended by each type of sensor and each type of sensor having it's own properties. Something like this:

```
                 +-----------+
                 |Sensor     |
                 +-----------+
                 |id         |
                 |location   |
                 |description|
                 +-----+-----+
                       ^
                       |
          +------------+-----------+- - - -
          |                        |
+---------+---------+      +-------+------+
|Temperature        |      |AirPressure   |
|Sensor             |      |Sensor        |
+-------------------+      +--------------+
|temperature : float|      |pressure : int|
+-------------------+      +--------------+
```

But that doesn't allow me to keep track of historical data. For that purpose I think I'd need some kind of 'Measurement' class to keep track of each sensors measurements over time.

```
                  +----------------------+    
                  |Measurement           |    
                  +----------------------+    +------+
                  |sensor : Sensor       +----+Sensor|
                  |tsMeasured : timestamp|    +------+
                  +-----+----------------+
                        ^
                        |
           +------------+-----------+- - - -
           |                        |
+----------+--------+       +-------+------+
|Temperature        |       |AirPressure   |
|Measurement        |       |Measurement   |
+-------------------+       +--------------+
|temperature : float|       |pressure : int|
+-------------------+       +--------------+
```

However, this starts duplicating the class-tree structure which feels wrong and will also make it more difficult to maintan a list of measurements at the level of the Sensor class.

Conceptually I'd want a Sensor class that has a reference to it's most current measurement and a list containing historical measurements. However, the type of the value in the measurement is dependent on the type of sensor. Is there a way of enforcing this such that I can simplify the model to something like

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|Sensor<SensorType>                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
|id                                          |
|location                                    |    +------------------------+
|measurements : List<Measurement<SensorType>>|----|Measurement<SensorType> |
+--------------------------------------------+    +------------------------+
                                                  |tsMeasured : timestamp  |
                                                  |value : <type dependent |
                                                  | on type of measurement>|
                                                  +------------------------+
```

I'm thinking towards Java's generic types, but obviously I don't know enough about them that I can come up with a working solution. But perhaps I am looking completely in the wrong direction :). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems you should be able to use generics precisely in the way you describe.

In this case, you might even not need any inheritance at all (if the sensors don't have any other data or operations). An air pressure sensor might simply be an instance of `Sensor<Integer>`, i.e.:

```
Sensor<Integer> airPressureSensor = new Sensor<>;
```

This might be shorter to write and easier to maintain than a whole hierarchy of Sensors.

If you must implement a `AirPressureSensor` class for some reason, you can do it like that:

```
class AirPressureSensor extends Sensor<Integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a pretty cool project to be working on. [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things) is becoming more and more popular these days and it brings with it it's own set of challenges.

I did some quick digging for existing IoT data models and found [this](http://ogc-iot.github.io/ogc-iot-api/datamodel.html). It looks like it suggests a similar approach in that a `sensor` has a `data-stream` and that `data-stream` has a `unitOfMeasurement`. So, perhaps it's not a bad start.

If you're going to be storing this historical data in a database and you have a wide variety of sensors which capture different data, it might be well suited to a NoSQL database that doesn't define a rigid schema like a traditional relational database does. My preference there would be [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).

I'd definitely suggest reading up on some IoT architectures/design patterns/frameworks first. DZone has an article about [Architecting the IoT](https://dzone.com/articles/architecting-the-internet-of-things).

Personally If I were to have a go at it I would likely use [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) to design some sort of pub-sub architecture where `things` that are interested in `sensors` can subscribe to that `sensors` channel and then make decisions about what to do. Spring Integration also has native support for MongoDB so historical usage could easily be taken care of by piping that data into a [MongoDB Outbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-outbound-channel-adapter). For bonus points you could even [post statuses to twitter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/twitter.html#twitter-outbound) when certain events happen.

There are loads of cool possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should read up on some of the existing techniques, libraries and frameworks that are out there. The article about Architecting the IoT references some interesting projects.